# Running multiple Unit Tests in an unit test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I am currently working on a project using C# and Visual Studio 2012.

I have a hard time trying to figure out why VS 2012 does not want to run all of my tests.

I have one test projects which runs 1 unit test out of 2. No matter what I've tried, it does not want to run the other unit test. It is not detected via the Test Explorer, the "Not Run" test does not include the file.

Here's a basic framework to put it clearly:

**(I have edited the framework to include every part of the solution)**

```
Solution
    MainProject
        ProjectA.Tests (that is the project)
           UnitTestsA.cs (Actually run)
           UnitTestsB.cs (Neven run)
```

Here's the code for the second unit test file:

```
using System; 
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; 
namespace MagicAdmin.Tests 
{      
    [TestClass] 
    public class UnitTest1 
    { 
        [TestMethod] 
        public void TestMethod1() 
        { } 
    } 
}
```

How can I solve this? What do I do wrong?

Comment: Presumably you have set the necessary attribute to make UnitTestsB.cs recognised by the test runner.  Can you provide some code please

Comment: Also, what Unit Test Framework are you using? NUnit?

Comment: Yes I could, what code do you want? I have my main project, my test project, the first test file and the second test file which never runs. NOTE: even if I put all the code in a Class using [TestClass] Attribute and put it at the end of the first test file, it still doesn't run.

Comment: I am using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting and the Test Explorer.

Comment: At a minimum, please start with the code for UnitTestsB.cs.

Comment: Well the code of interest is probably the UnitTestB.cs.  How many tests in there? I assume they are all failing?

Comment: Here it is @JeffSiver:

using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MagicAdmin.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
        }
    }
}

Comment: @ScruffyDuck No because the are not even detected by the test explorer. I have 76 tests (counted) in the first file and 3 tests in the second. The Test Explorer tells me it ran 76 test. If I try to right-click and run tests / debug tests in a test method, for example, it never even reaches those parts.

Comment: Silly question, but have you rebuilt the assembly since you made the new tests?

Comment: @JohnKoerner That is not a silly question. I have built the solution many times, but not the assembly. Were you talking of this?

Comment: @HervéSimard Yes.  Basically if you rebuild the solution, but the current build config is not setup to build the unit test assembly, then it you will not see the tests.  Try building the assembly only via a right click in solution explorer.

Comment: @HervéSimard Is TestMethod1 really empty of any code?  If so why would it be run?

Comment: @JohnKoerner VS2012 will by default rebuild the solution when you run the tests, so I do not believe that is the problem

Comment: @JohnKoerner Ok, I've tried, and I may get something. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: Keep pouring in ideas and comments, you're helping me! Thanks! ^^

Comment: Seems like it worked! Thanks @JohnKoerner!

Comment: I am having the exact same problem but this solution did not help.  Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Visual Studio to recognize your unit tests, you need to rebuild the unit test project.  It is possible that the unit test project is not set to build as part of your current build configuration and thus is not being built when you build the solution.

Comment: I'm skeptical your suggestion to rebuild the unit test project works. I have a solution which contains two projects `Bank` and `BankTest`. `BankTest` contains two `.cs` files: `BankAccountConstructorTest.cs` and `BankAccountTest.cs`. Each of those `.cs` files contain a `[TestClass]` class and, within in it, at least one `[TestMethod]` methods. The test methods in `BankAccountConstructorTest.cs` were visible to `Test Explorer` while those in `BankAccountTest.cs` were not. Rebuilding `BankTest` *(right click > rebuild)*  did not make them visible to `Test Explorer`.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this problem, but just figured out a solution.

I am building a .NET Core library for use in a DotNet console app. There is a separate solution for the library. The library contains projects for the library, a unit test project, and a showcase project.

I followed the steps in these articles:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/testing-library-with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/consuming-library-with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp

I added some extra library classes in the library, and I made sure to change the package version for the lbirary. I rebuilt the library, and published it to NuGET.

I added an extra class in the test project, and could not get the routine in the test class to run.  I had followed these steps:
 - Added a regular C# class to the test project
 - Added [TestClass] at the top of the class
 - Added a public void method, and added [TestMethod] above it
 - Used manage NuGET projects on the test project, and made sure I updated to the latest version of the library package

But "Run All" was not seeing the extra test.

I finally discovered that the new testing class needed to be declared as public!  Then the next Run All properly picked up the extra test method in the new test class.

Here is an outline of the necessary things in the extra testing class:

```
using System;
using UtilityLib.APIDir;

namespace UtilityLibTest
{
   [TestClass]
   public class UnitTest_NewAPI
   {
       [TestMethod]
       public void TestNewAPI()
       {
          NewAPI tester = new NewAPI();
          bool someResult = tester.DoSomething();
       }
   }
}
```

Other comments on Visual Studio projects:

There are several issues with Visual Studio, where shutting down all copies of Visual Studio, and restarting, can fix problems.

When I created my first .Net core lib project, published it to NuGET, and then used NuGET to load it into another project, but I was unable to reference the classes within the library. I started looking into some tools to try to look into the NuGET package.

But after system restart (For an entirely unrelated issue), I restarted Visual Studio, and then I was able to access the library classes from my main project.

Another issue is from a project that consumes a nuget library, sometimes after updating the version of the assembly with nuget, the calling program might not be able to access the namespaces or classes in the updated library. A rebuild all on the calling project fixed that problem for me yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out my problem. I think most people encounter this problem same as me. The root problem is that I add the unit test class in the wrong way. Try to  re-add the file using the "Test" section. This would make the class get dependency to the project. Otherwise, the project did not include it when running test.

Answer (score 0):

if you just add 2nd C# class file to manage your 2nd set of test code in single unit test project, make sure those things happen.

1. **Decorate it with the right test keyword attributes** to tell Visual
   studio this is a test class , method , example....

> "MS unit test" ,  test class attribute =  [TestClass] , test method attribute = [TestMethod]
>
> "xUnit" ,  test method  attribute =  [Fact]

2. **Make sure class , method is set as public**

something like this shall help
[image]